# Software that can perform QMC on quantum Ising model

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, ising-model

I'm trying to find a software that can perform QMC using the loop algorithm as outlined in the following lecture notes:
https://www.cond-mat.de/events/correl13/manuscripts/wessel.pdf

The closest software I've found is qmcpack, but it seems to work only with continuous wavefunctions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this Python package should do it, see [link part I](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhys.2.1.003/pdf) and [link part II](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhys.7.2.020/pdf). I just refered to the links, despite possible downvotes.